# How to draw a circular UIImage on Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics, uibezierpath

Inside custom `UIView`, I've overridden `draw()` function. I need to draw an image in a circular layout. Also, if possible, I need to resize the image keeping the **aspect fill/fit** property. How to do that?

**Code:**

```
@IBDesignable class ScoreGraphView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "women"))
        iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        iv.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height))
    }
}
```

This above lines can be used for drawing image. `cornerRadius`/`masksToBounds` are not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cornerRadius ` only work if you also set `masksToBounds = true`

Comment: @Tj3n do you mean clipToBounds = true? I have also tried it but no luck.

Comment: `iv.layer.masksToBounds =  true` does not work? It work fine for me, maybe in your `draw ` function you override something?

Comment: @Tj3n I have posted full source for the custom uiview, its still drawing full rectangle image. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Try remove `iv.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height))`

Comment: Then how the image will be drawn? @Tj3n

Comment: You already init the imageview with an image, you dont need call draw

Comment: imageView is instantiated but how uiview will know how & where to add this imageView? did u try urself? @Tj3n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the clue,

```
let userimageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: rect)
userimageView.image = UIImage(named: "women")
userimageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
userimageView.alpha = 1.0
userimageView.clipsToBounds = false
userimageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
userimageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

self.layer.addSublayer(userimageView.layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

2nd Attempt :

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    layer.cornerRadius = 20
    clipsToBounds = true
    let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "women"))
    iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
    iv.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height))
}
```

Comment: App crashed!, `fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: `

Comment: I've edited my answer - as I was dynamically adding a ScoreGraphView in code.

Comment: This works but only when drawn in full view, what if i want to draw the image in a point (10,10) with size (50,50), but still want circular. And also the background is always black. I tried with self.backgroudColor = UIColor.white & iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear but did not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imgProfile.frame.size.height/2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an IBDesignable, have you looked at your clipsToBounds property in the storyboard for the ScoreGraphView?

Try adding this to your class ScoreGraphView as well:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```